# Ubuntu 22.04 remote desktop RDP no sound

Tags: gnome, sound, rdp

Installed a clean Ubuntu 22.04

Enabled the built-in remote desktop. I connect from windows 10. Everything works except audio transmission.

:~$ inxi -SMA

```
System:
  Host: rdp Kernel: 5.19.0-32-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Console: pty pts/0
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Qemu System: QEMU product: Standard PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009) v: pc-q35-7.1
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: N/A model: N/A serial: N/A UEFI: EFI Development Kit II / OVMF v: 0.0.0
    date: 02/06/2015
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 82801I HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: NVIDIA driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-3: Intel 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-32-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

:~$ journalctl -b -t pulseaudio

```
feb 26 19:56:26 rdp pulseaudio[877]: Failed to find a working profile.
feb 26 19:56:26 rdp pulseaudio[877]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1b.0" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
feb 26 19:56:27 rdp pulseaudio[877]: Unable to load mixer: Недопустимый аргумент
feb 26 19:56:27 rdp pulseaudio[877]: Unable to load mixer: Недопустимый аргумент
feb 26 19:56:27 rdp pulseaudio[877]: Disabling timer-based scheduling because running inside a VM.
feb 26 19:56:27 rdp pulseaudio[877]: Disabling timer-based scheduling because running inside a VM.
feb 26 19:56:27 rdp pulseaudio[877]: Failed to find a working profile.
feb 26 19:56:27 rdp pulseaudio[877]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1b.0" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
feb 26 19:56:52 rdp pulseaudio[877]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

There is only one sound card in the audio parameters in the output devices. There is no xrdp-sink source like in XRDP.
If you use XRDP, the sound is transmitted, but the drawing speed is much worse.
How to reset (activate) the sound using the standard RDP in ubuntu 22.04?

Answer (score 2):

> How to reset (activate) the sound using the standard RDP in ubuntu 22.04?

The standard RDP service in Ubuntu 22.04 is gnome-remote-desktop (g-r-d).
Audio output forwarding in g-r-d was implemented in GNOME 43 ([0](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-remote-desktop/-/merge_requests/104) + some improvements in [1](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-remote-desktop/-/merge_requests/163)) (also requires PipeWire for audio handling), however Ubuntu 22.04 uses GNOME 42 (and Pulseaudio).

You basically need a newer GNOME version installed and PipeWire as audio handler configured (should be already the case with Ubuntu 22.10 and later).

It should be noted, that the audio transmission for g-r-d in Ubuntu won't be as efficient as in other distributions, as Ubuntu does (at least currently) not build g-r-d with fdk-aac enabled (That would depend on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fdk-aac/+bug/1977614).

So, with Ubuntu 22.10 (and later), g-r-d has audio transmission.

(Compared though to e.g. g-r-d on Fedora 37 or g-r-d on Archlinux it would take more bandwidth on Ubuntu (which MAY have an impact on the stutter handling as well), since without fdk-aac, the individual audio packets are larger than 1600Bytes and need to be split.)